# Fail a big stream in AkkaStreams by a minimum of elements

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have following situation:
A stream of at least 10M elements. But there is a minimum of 1M, the stream must fail if the minimum is not reached.
The stream is implemented in Akka Streams like that:

```
Source.range(0,10_000_000).via(someBusiness())
.runWith(Sink.ignore(),actorSystem);
```

A sink such as Sink.seq() is not an option because I don't want such big collections in memory.

I would expect any Flow, that counts the elements and verify the count when stream ends.

Answer (score 1):

The broad idea is to:

- transform every incoming element from the source into a wrapper (a single-element array is probably the easiest way in Java (which is what I'm guessing you're writing this in) to accomplish this)
- `concat` a `Source.single` which generates a wrapper which is easily distinguishable (e.g. a zero-element array); the stream will not go to this source until the main source has been exhausted
- track the element count and throw if the minimum number of elements has not been reached and we see the `concat`ted element; otherwise unwrap the element

So something like (apologies if the Java is atrocious)

```java
int[] zeroElems = new int[0];

Source.range(0, 10_000_000)
    .map(x -> {
        int[] wrapped = new int[1];
        wrapped[0] = x;
        return wrapped;
    })
    .concat(Source.single(zeroElems))
    .statefulMapConcat(
        () -> {
            // trick to get around Java prohibition of closing over non-final variables
            final int[] counter = {0};
            return (wrapper) -> {
                if (counter[0] < 1_000_000) {
                    if (wrapper.length < 1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Insufficient number of elements in stream");
                    }

                    counter[0]++; 
                }

                return Arrays.stream(wrapper).iterator();
            }
        }
    )
    .via(someBusiness())
    .runWith(Sink.ignore(), actorSystem)
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution. That would restrict the type of the streamed elements to an int array, which is for me not an good idea. Also it exposes the state. I hoped to find a solution with the akka stream api.

Comment: For things which aren't primitives, you could probably use Java `Optional` (with an empty `Optional` to signal completion)... in Scala, it would be pretty straightforward and idiomatic to just use an `Option` (which is probably why there's nothing directly in the API).